# Change text in another div from clicking another Item in list using Vue.js + typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Still get the hang of Vue, so forgive my lack of knowledge here. I am currently trying to change the text of another div to match the item I selected in my list. Below is a codesanbox as well as what I currently have.

Codesanbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-ts-mod-forked-5fbvd

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-menu bottom left>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn text class="align-self-center mr-4" v-on="on">
          {{ item.car }} <----this is failing, should match the item I selected in the menu
          <v-icon small class="pl-3">fa-caret-down</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>

      <v-list class="lighten-3">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, index) in cars"
          :key="index"
          @click="addItem(item)"
        >
          {{ item.car }}
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Dropdown extends Vue {
  public cars: any[] = [
    { id: 2, car: "GZ", configs: null },
    { id: 3, car: "AB", configs: null },
    { id: 5, car: "C4", configs: null },
    { id: 1, car: "PA", configs: null },
  ];

  public addItem(item): void {
    console.log("item==========", item);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `currentItem` property and update one you click on the list item inside the `addItem` method:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-menu bottom left>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn v-if="currentItem" text class="align-self-center mr-4" v-on="on">
          {{ currentItem.car }} 
          <v-icon small class="pl-3">fa-caret-down</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>

      <v-list class="lighten-3">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, index) in cars"
          :key="index"
          @click="addItem(item)"
        >
          {{ item.car }}
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Dropdown extends Vue {
  public currentItem:any=null
  public cars: any[] = [
    { id: 2, car: "GZ", configs: null },
    { id: 3, car: "AB", configs: null },
    { id: 5, car: "C4", configs: null },
    { id: 1, car: "PA", configs: null },
  ];

  public addItem(item): void {
   this.currentItem=item
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'car' of null" back

Comment: Try to add `v-if="currentItem"` to `v-btn`

Comment: i updated my answer, but you should also add custom type

Answer (score 1):

Your first `item.car` is outside the for loop, you therefore cannot access the item.

Change the first `item.car` into `selectedItem.car`.

Add a `data` function on your component:

```js
data () {
    return {
        selectedItem: { car : '' }
    }
}
```

Now change your `addItem` function to:

```js
addItem (item) {
    this.selectedItem = item
}
```

Basically we assign the selected item to a component data property which is reactive and accessible by your first div.

Note that the above code is not TS code, but you'll get the point.

Comment: Yes this is valid when we use javascript version